# Sequence contains no elements exception in linq without even using Single

Tags: c#, string, linq, linq-to-objects, sequences

I am not using `Single` in LINQ below, but I am still getting a 'Sequence contains no elements' exception:

```
allNames = StockCollection.Where((s) => s.Name.IndexOf("A") == 0)
                          .Select((s) => s.Name)
                          .Aggregate((namesInfo, name) => namesInfo += ", " + name);
```

This exception comes when there is no stock starting with name `'A'`.

It seems that one extension method is expecting atleast one element satisfying the condition but that's not expected.

Can you please suggest the best solution to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As Dennis Traub has pointed out, the overload of `Aggregate` you are using throws that exception when the source sequence is empty.

The obvious fix is to use the [other overload of `Aggregate` that accepts an initial seed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) (you want `string.Empty`), but that would result in a leading comma in the result which you'll have to get rid of.

(**EDIT**: You can dodge this with `.DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)` followed by your existing `Aggregate` overload. This wouldn't produce a leading comma.)

In any case, using `Aggregate` like that to join strings isn't a great idea (produces a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)). Here's how I would write the query:

```
allNames = string.Join(",", StockCollection.Select(s => s.Name)
                                           .Where(name => name.StartsWith("A"));
```

In .NET 3.5, you'll need a .`ToArray()` to materialize the `Where` results into an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply i am going to try this now.. But still i want to know why aggregate is throwing an exception.

Comment: @D J: Why? What sensible value could it return? Perhaps the default value of the return type (`null` in this case), but I wouldn't want that.

Comment: Problem is like we dont know at the runtime our collection will have any object or not? so it should not throw an exception or it can just return default value.

Comment: +1 for `DefaultIfEmpty` this works well with examples more complex than strings.

Comment: If I could, I'd give you a second upvote for for the "in .NET 3.5" tip - thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Use with empty seed.

```
new string[]{}.Aggregate("", (a,b)=> a+b )
```

Comment: I think, that instead of "" should use string.Empty

Comment: For readability I agree that string.Empty is better, but there's no difference in allocations between "" and string.Empty since .Net 2 I believe.

Answer (score 6):

Using Aggregate(func) on an empty source throws an InvalidOperationException.

See documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx