# Get the product of a list using java Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

How do you get the product of a array using java Lambdas. I know in C# it is like this:

`result = array.Aggregate((a, b) => b * a);`

edit: made the question more clear.

Comment: This operation is called "reduction". Tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list.stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
```

Comment: Question is a bit confusing, saying `list`, but code saying `array`, so maybe show both?

Comment: The example from another language uses `array`, but everything else asks for the product of a list.

Comment: Also, `reduce((a, b) -> b * a).orElseXxx()` is technically closer to the C# version shown, though I don't know which `orElseXxx()` method is appropriate, since C# documentation doesn't seem to describe result when called on empty input.

Comment: @Andreas, it would be closest to `reduce(...).get()`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867867/sequence-contains-no-elements-exception-in-linq-without-even-using-single).

Answer (score 0):

You mention both arrays and lists, so here is how you would do it for both:

```
Integer intProduct = list.stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);   
Integer intProduct = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);  // Integer[]
int intProduct = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);  // int[]
```

That version has one drawback if the list/array might be empty: the first argument, `1` in this case, will be returned as the result if the list or array are empty, so if you don't want that behavior, there is a version that will return an `Optional<Integer>`, OptionalInt, etc.:

```
Optional<Integer> intProduct = list.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a * b);   
Optional<Integer> intProduct = Arrays.stream(array).reduce((a, b) -> a * b);  // Integer[] 
OptionalInt intProduct = Arrays.stream(array).reduce((a, b) -> a * b);  // int[]
```